# Xpath how to select xmlns atribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml that starts like that

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><History xmlns="http://www.tandberg.no/XML/CUIL/1.0">
```

And i'm having problem selecting elements in it because of this namespace. I want to select it and delete using xmlstarlet.

I tried:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//@xmlns' history.xml
```

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//@[local-name()=xmlns]' history.xml
```

But all the time i get "xpath set is empty"

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespace declarations aren't attributes in the XPath data model, so you can't select them as if they were.

"Deleting a namespace" is actually changing the name of the element, from a name in a specific namespace, to a name in no namespace. I don't know xmlstarlet, but you need to be looking for a "rename" action.